# Create keys randomly with PHP

Tags: php, regex, random

I have an mobile app that request a key in my server, The key structure contains 7 characters as follows:

```
@ + [0-9] + [0-9] + [0-9] + [A-Z] + [A-Z] + [0-9] 

@876EU8, @668KI2 .......
```

Whereas the key initially has seven characters, in this case three numbers, two letters and one number, doing the math this gives a maximum of 676,000 keys.

To gerate this keys I'm using this code in PHP:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 2) {
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$randomKeyNumber = rand(100,999);
$randomKeyLetter = generateRandomString();
$randomKeyLast = rand(0,9);

$randomKey = "#".$randomKeyNumber.$randomKeyLetter.$randomKeyLast;//Returns a key like @876TG9
```

The next code check if the key exists inside the database, If exists he random another key, if not he insert the key in database and return this key to my app

This code works perfectly, but assuming the system has already generated a total of 650,000 keys, in the case of this code it would always generate the same keys, and the likelihood of it generate a key that does not exist yet is very small.

How can I solve this problem and avoid future problems? (There is no problem in creating the keys in an orderly manner, eg 000AA0, 000AA1, 000AA2, 000AA3 .... 999ZZ9)

Comment: Can you limit a key's lifetime?

Comment: @fvu, Well as you can see my app is new and I got to thinking about this possibility, but as the app is new think initially I should not think about it now, though I do not know if my app will have more than 600,000 downloads.... So in this case the keys not have a lifetime.

Comment: @fvu, When you download my app and open him first time, will be request a key, that key is single for each device.

Comment: "There is no problem in creating the keys in an orderly manner, eg 000AA0, 000AA1, 000AA2, 000AA3 .... 999ZZ9". Then just do it this way. Whenever a new key is needed, take the last one and increase by 1.

Comment: As your keyspace is rather small I must agree with @ElmoVanKielmo, using them sequentially at least guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, In this case I will need to create 3 column inside my database, the first column save the actual 3 numbers of the last key gerated, the second save the actual 2 numbers, and other save the actual last number...In php I get this 3 values inside my database increase 1 and save, If the last is 9 I increase 1 in that 3 numbers and when I get 999AA9 I increase to 000AB0 and go in this way,

Comment: Nope. You need one column for the entire key. You split the string in PHP and the rest of your algorithm is ok.

Comment: But guys I have a little fear about this method, let's assume that 20 devices once downloaded my app and made the request to my server, what is the probability of an error and two different devices  or more possess the same key?

Comment: You can pre-compute all the keys (in order), assign a random value from 0 to 650k to each, sort (to randomize them) then use the result set sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make a `PDO::query()` to issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` or simply a `SELECT *` statement with all the keys you already have added, and then use [PDOStatement::fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned (i.e. in this case, all of them)

This is a manual example

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Keys";
if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

        /* Issue the real SELECT statement and work with the results */
         $sql = "SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
       foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
           print "Name: " .  $row['NAME'] . "\n";
         }
    }
    /* No rows matched -- do something else */
  else {
      print "No rows matched the query.";
    }
}

$res = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

This is the code you need for your case:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * From Keys";

if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

        /* and then you get the id of the last one on the list, and to that one you add 1 */
         $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
         $new_id = $last_id + 1;
/* then you insert that in some place inside the key itself, that way you don't need to worry than two keys can be equal */
    }

  else {
      /* No rows matched, just create a key and add to the database here */
    }
}
¿>
```

Alternatively you can make a query SELECT statement combined with the [countRows](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) in PDO, it doesn't work all the times in the portable apps and/or databases, but like we don't know more about your app we can't know if this is gonna work.

PS. Don't use [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php). Use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead. It is more efficient with the resources of the server ;)